# Number of Zeros in the Right Half Plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having a bit of trouble with the following exercise:

Determine the number of solutions to the equation

$$z-2 -e^{-z} = 0$$

in the right half plane $P = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : \Re(z)> 0\}$.

I was thinking of using Rouche's theorem solve this, however, I am not sure if this is the right idea.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Rouché's theorem is a great idea (as long as you handle correctly the fact that the boundary of the right half-plane isn't a closed curve). How do the functions $z-2$ and $e^{-z}$ compare on that boundary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take, $f(z)=z-2$ and $g(z)=-e^{-z}$. Take, $\{z:|z-2|<1\}\subset P$.

Now, on $|z-2|=1$ ,  $|g(z)|=|e^{-\Re (z)-i\Im(z)}|=e^{-\Re (z)}<1=|f(z)|$.

Since , $f$ has only one zero so, $z-2-e^{-z}$ has only one zero in $\{z:|z-2|<1\}$

Comment: Thanks!  This was exactly what I was thinking but I wasn't positive, but now I am!  Awesome!

Comment: @user0430) I checked your profile today...I found that you only upvote on the answer without accepting the answer...No answer is accepted by you...It is improper..I advice you to accept my answer..and not only that accept all the answers of your question which answers are proper to you..If I see this before answering this answer I never give you the answer...I think you understand what I am saying....

Comment: @user0430)  I think you could not understand my above comment..I will follow you regularly..If you does not accept the other answers you will never get any answer from any other users in future ...It is NOT possible that all the answers are acceptable to you..If it is then update your previous questions by adding additional lines so that you can get more appropriate answer.

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment.  I only accepted answers two answers.  Your solution is just a direct application of Rouche's theorem, and hence, your solution is pretty straightforward.

Comment: According to your comment, the other answers of your previous questions are not helpful to you .,,... Is it???

Comment: @Empty Why isn't it possible for there to be roots to the equation in right-half plane but not in the disc at $z=2$ with radius $1$? How does one rule this out?

Comment: @user193319 because at a zero z, 
$$z-2=e^{-z}\implies |z-2|=|e^{-z}|<1$$
where inequality follows from $\Re(z)>0$. Thus, all roots are contained in the disk that Empty provided.